# ArcGIS Online webmap and Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, arcgis-online-webmap

I am looking for more information on how to display ArcGIS Online/Portal Web Maps inside my existing application that uses OpenLayers to display maps.

Im looking for something simple as the following sample that was created using the ArcGIS JavaScript API => https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/webmap-basic/

But since my application was already created using OpenLayers, I will need to have it to load the ArcGIS Online webmaps.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.